# Sqlite database in android application working but it comes with double entry(insert) in table

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, sqliteopenhelper

I have made an application in android and used Sqlite database for storing data. I have tried sqlite Open helper and made class for it. It's working well but the problem is that when I insert the data, it is inserted twice in table.

My Code is as below:

**db-helper.java**

```
package com.example.timerdemo2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    
    public static String db_name = "myDB.db";
    public static String Name = "name";
    public static String Timerpoint1 = "timerpoint1";
    public static String Timerpoint2 = "timerpoint2";
    public static String Timerpoint3 = "timerpoint3";
    public static String Servicetime1 = "servicetime1";
    public static String Servicetime2 = "servicetime2";

    public dbhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, db_name, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
try{
        
            
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE timer(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Name TEXT,Timerpoint1 TEXT,Timerpoint2 TEXT,Timerpoint3 TEXT,Servicetime1 TEXT,Servicetime2 TEXT);");
            /*String sql = "INSERT INTO register (Email,Name,Contact)" + "VALUES (" + Email + "," + Name + "," + Contact + ")";
            db.execSQL(sql);*/
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.util.Log.v("Constants", "Upgrading database which will destroy all data");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**TimeDetails.java**

```
package com.example.timerdemo2;

import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.jar.Attributes.Name;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Timedetails extends Activity {
EditText eta,etb,etc,service1,service2;
Button btn,btn1;
TextView tv1;
SQLiteDatabase db;

dbhelper dh = new dbhelper(this);

/*@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}  */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timedetails);
        
        Bundle b1 = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        final String title = b1.getString("title");
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Projecttitle);
        tv1.setText(title);
        
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String tim1 = bundle.getString("t1");
        String tim2 = bundle.getString("t2");
        String tim3 = bundle.getString("t3");
        
        final String titl = bundle.getString("titl1");
        final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Projecttitle);
        tv.setText(titl);
        
        eta = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.timval1);
        eta.setText(tim1);
        etb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.timval2);
        etb.setText(tim2);
        etc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.timval3);
        etc.setText(tim3);
        
     String ser1 = bundle.getString("dif1");
     String ser2 = bundle.getString("dif2");
     
        
        service1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.servicetime1a);
        service1.setText(ser1);
        service2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.servicetime2a);
        service2.setText(ser2);
        
     //   btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
      /*  btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showMessageAlert();
            }

        /*  private void showMessageAlert() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Timedetails.this);
                                final Dialog dialog = null;
                            builder.setTitle("Alert");
                            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete");

                            builder.setCancelable(true);
                            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                            builder.setPositiveButton("I Accept",   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                  // dialog.dismiss();
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(Timedetails.this,ListActivity.class);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Time Details has been Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                     // delete the stuff you wan to 
                                }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("I decline",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    //Do nothing
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            alert.show();
                        }
                    });
            }
        });*/
        
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent intent =new Intent(Timedetails.this,ListActivity.class); 
                 //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Project has been added to List", 1).show();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    addRecord();
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record inserted successfully !", 1).show();
                addRecord();
            }

            private void addRecord() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String tv1 = tv.getText().toString();
                tv.setText(tv1);
               //String title = tv1.getText().toString();
                //tv1.setText(tv);
                String tmp1 = eta.getText().toString();
                String tmp2 = etb.getText().toString();
                String tmp3 = etc.getText().toString();
                String ser1 = service1.getText().toString();
                String ser2 = service2.getText().toString();
                insertData(titl,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,ser1,ser2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record inserted suceessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }

            private void insertData(String titl, String tmp1, String tmp2,
                    String tmp3, String ser1, String ser2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), titl + " " + tmp1 + " " + tmp2 + " "+ tmp3 + " "+ ser1 +" "+ ser2, 1).show();
                SQLiteDatabase db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(dh.Name, titl);
                cv.put(dh.Timerpoint1, tmp1);
                cv.put(dh.Timerpoint2, tmp2);
                cv.put(dh.Timerpoint3, tmp3);
                cv.put(dh.Servicetime1, ser1);
                cv.put(dh.Servicetime2, ser2);
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + cv, 1).show();
                db.insert("timer", dh.Name, cv);
                
                
 
            }
            
            
        });
         }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
    }
    
}
```

**ListActivity.java**

```
package com.example.timerdemo2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.menu;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> items_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    dbhelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private boolean Distinct = true;
    int index_id;
    Button btn;
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        Button btn;
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newProjectlist);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            
                    Intent intent= new Intent(ListActivity.this,NewProject.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });  
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.projectListView);
        setUpList();
        dh = new dbhelper(this);
        Cursor c = getAllData();
        showAllData(c);  
        registerForContextMenu(lv);      
    }
      
  @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        
        if(v.getId() == R.id.projectList){
            menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Record List");
            menu.add(0,1,menu.NONE,"Delete Record");
            menu.add(0,2,menu.NONE,"Show Record");
        }
    }

    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if(itemId == 1)
        {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo;
            menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            index_id = menuinfo.position;
            deleteUserData(index_id);
        }
        if(itemId == 2){
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo;
            menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            index_id = menuinfo.position;
            editUserData(index_id);
        }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
  
    private void editUserData(int indexid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String user_id = items_id.get(indexid);
        Intent intEdit = new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intEdit.putExtra("EditID", user_id);
        startActivityForResult(intEdit, 1);
    }
    
    private void deleteUserData(int indexid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String user_id = items_id.get(indexid);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id " + user_id, 1).show();
        db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("timer","_ID" + "=" + user_id, null);
        finish();
//      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record deleted successfully", 1).show();
    }
    
    private void showAllData(Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            String name = c.getString(1);
            String timerpoint1 = c.getString(2);
            String timerpoint2 = c.getString(3);
            String timerpoint3 = c.getString(4);
            String servicetime1 = c.getString(5);
            String servicetime2 = c.getString(6);
            items.add("" + name);
            items_id.add(""+id);
        }
        setUpList();
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Cursor getAllData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db = dh.getReadableDatabase();
        //String sortorder = dh.Name + "DESC";
    //  String query ="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM timer";
    //  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //   if (c != null) {
    //            c.moveToFirst();
    //        }
           
        Cursor cur = db.query(Distinct,"timer", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cur);
        return cur; 
        }
    private void setUpList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));
    }   
    
    }
```

Comment: where's the insert method?

Comment: @mango-brother i have updates the code...can u please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inserting twice because your insert method is called twice. (via `addRecord` here)

```
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent =new Intent(Timedetails.this,ListActivity.class); 
            //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Project has been added to List", 1).show();
            startActivity(intent);
            addRecord(); <--------- add once
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record inserted successfully !", 1).show();
            addRecord(); <---------- added a second time!
        }
```

Comment: Mango--Thanx brother....thank you very much....its working.........!hav a good day...god bless u...

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the Insert statement to a new method other than onCreate for the dbHelper Class.
  *The data is being inserted for the number of times the class is called.

Comment: @Rahul--Please help me ...rahul

Comment: Am glad you got your answer, but I did not -ve vote you answer or any other answer for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent =new Intent(Timedetails.this,ListActivity.class); 
        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Project has been added to List", 1).show();
        startActivity(intent);
        addRecord(); <--------- add once
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record inserted successfully !", 1).show();
        addRecord(); <---------- added a second time!
    }
```